# permission denied exception when sending mail javamail

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

HI When I try to send a mail from java mail I got exception but it will work for one email adddress ("abil").  Please help me.

```
String smtpServer = "mail.xxxxxx.yy" ;
String user =  abil;
String password = password;
String sPort = "";
String sSSL = "";
String hostName = "";


Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpServer);
props.put("mail.from", from);
props.put("mail.debug", useDebug ? "true" : "false");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
if (hostName != null && !hostName.trim().isEmpty()) {
props.put("mail.smtp.localhost", hostName);
}
if (!user.trim().isEmpty()) {
props.put("mail.user", user);
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
}
if (usingSSL) {
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
}
```

I can send a mail using "abil" as sender. but when I can send a mail using "bill" as sender I got below exception ,

```
    22/12/2016 06:56:04.956 - Emailer [INFO] : Properties: {mail.smtp.port=25, mail.debug=true, mail.from=bill, mail.transport.protocol=smtp, mail.user=abil, mail.smtp.auth=true, mail.smtp.host=mail.xxxxxx.yy}
22/12/2016 06:56:04.958 - Emailer [EXCEPTION] : Exception Occurred
org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 5.7.1 <bil@......xy>... Permission denied
        at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:486)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:95)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:48)
        at modules.email.Emailer.lambda$sendEmail$150(Emailer.java:222)
        at util.ThreadPool$TaskWrapper.run(ThreadPool.java:32)
        at util.ThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPool.java:139)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Why I cant able to send a mail when the sender is changed to "bill@xyx@abc". 
I can send a mail if my sender is same as user.

Thank you very much,

Comment: According to your log the mail.user is still abil while you're trying to send as bil. That won't work...

Comment: Without seeing the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug), I'm guessing that you're authenticating as "abil" and then trying to send as "bill", which your server is not going to allow to prevent spoofing the From address.

Answer (score 0):

The sender 'bill' may not have permissions to send mail

Comment: I dont think the user is a problem for me. USer is same for both cases. The only difference is with the sender, I cant able to send a mail when the sender is bill

Comment: Sorry I have edited the answer. Did mean the sender. An SMTP server will authenticate based on the parameters passed.